# Getting keyValuePair based on filtering of keys

Tags: c#, dictionary

I use myDictionary.Keys.Where to get a sequence but it returns just the keys (my predicate imposes conditions on keys). I would need to get the associated values as well and I am not sure how to do it easily, I am sure I miss some basic functionality..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, long>();
```

Something like:

```
IEnumerable<long> myvalues = dict.Where(x => x.Key == "A" || x.Key == "B")
                                 .Select(x => x.Value);
```

that will return the `Value`s you wanted

or

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, long>> myvalues = dict.Where(x => x.Key == "A" || x.Key == "B");
```

The last will return the full `KeyValuePair<string, long>`, with two properties (`Key` and `Value`)

Another (slower) solution:

```
IEnumerable<long> myvalues = dict.Keys.Where(x => x == "A" || x == "B")
                                      .Select(x => dict[x]);
```

it is slower because after filtering you lookup the dictionary for the `Key`s you found.

Comment: Thankis, I use a <string, long> pair